# Redirect 301 using regexp in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am looking for a Regex to redirect urls like:

```
example.net/example-1
example.net/example-2
example.net/example-3
```

I have many URLs that have the same prefix, but a different suffix after `example-`.

I was trying around with regex.

```
Redirect 301 /example-.*$ http://example.net/example-overview
Redirect 301 /example-(.*)? http://example.net/example-overview
Redirect 301 /example-(.+)[/]?$ http://example.net/example-overview
Redirect 301 /([^/example-]+) http://example.net/example-overview
```

I can't get it work.
Normal redirects for example `example-1` to `example-overview` are working fine.

**EDIT:
Found a solution:**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example-(.+)[/]?$ http://example.net/example-overview
```

Answer (score 2):

[Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) doesn't support regular expressions, use [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for that.